# store limited set of records per column name in counter column family having same rowkey

Tags: cassandra, hector

while using counter column family we can maually update values of counter say c1, c2 using cli

how to achieve this using hector client,i want counter column to accept only 20(e.g.) records and than after new column c2 (with 20 rec) and than c3 and so on

select * from timecontentcounter;

```
 key        | column1 | value
------------+---------+-------
 2013053015 |      c1 |    20
 2013053015 |      c2 |    20
```

In above example new column c3 should be generated to accept counter increments upto 20 records ,hector solution is needed

Answer (score 0):

This is not supported and won't ever be.  Maybe you should ask a different question along the lines of, "How should I model X?"

Comment: thanks for the answer...yes you are right...but I did the same programatically....and it works fine ..what I did is before inserting record in CF I fisrt check Counter CF and if its limit reached I made new column in Counter CF and than inserted record into that new Counter CF